# Changing layout in devise

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have two layouts

```
 layouts/application.html.erb
 layouts/profiles.html.erb
```

Controller:

```
 class ProfilesController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 end
```

Now I want `profiles layout` to be only used for `ProfilesController` all other `devise controllers` should use `application layout` but my `Devise::RegistrationsController` is currently using `profiles layout` by default. How do I change that?

Answer (score 1):

It is [documented in project page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-custom-layouts). I hope it helps.

UPDATE

And in your current project, you say `RegistrationController` is using `profiles` layout. This is obviously manually set in somewhere in your project as it s not default layout. Just search in your project where it is set and change it.